# Prolog: Implement Rule with Optional Facts

Tags: prolog

If I have a disease `disease1` which has five symptoms; `symptom1`, `symptom2`, `symptom3`, `symptom4` and `symptom5` but `symptom5` is optional. Would this be the best way to write the rule:

```
symptom('John', symptom1).
symptom('John', symptom2).
symptom('John', symptom3).
symptom('John', symptom4).

has_disease1(Person) :-
    symptom(Person, symptom1),
    symptom(Person, symptom2),
    symptom(Person, symptom3),
    symptom(Person, symptom4),
    symptom(Person, symptom5).

has_disease1(Person) :-
    symptom(Person, symptom1),
    symptom(Person, symptom2),
    symptom(Person, symptom3),
    symptom(Person, symptom4),
    not(symptom(Person, symptom5)).
```

Is there a way that the rule shoule be written?

Comment: If `symptom5` is only optional,why is it then relevant at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically if a symptom is optional then it is basically irrelevant.
So your rule would be

```
has_disease1(Person) :-
    symptom(Person, symptom1),
    symptom(Person, symptom2),
    symptom(Person, symptom3),
    symptom(Person, symptom4).
```

Comment: replace semicolon with period